# How to use @hapi/joi with this Mongoose Schema?

Tags: node.js, joi

I'm trying to make my nodejs api work with Joi but it wont work.
What i'm doing wrong? This is my business model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

// Define collection and schema for Business
let Business = new Schema({
  model: {
    type: Joi.string().alphanum().min(2).max(255).required()
  },
  brand: {
    type: Joi.string().alphanum().min(2).max(255).trim()
  },
  price: {
    type: Joi.number().positive()
  },
  photo: {
    type: Joi.string().max(255).trim()
  }
},{
    collection: 'business'
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Business', Business);
```

And this is my business route:

```
const express = require('express');
const businessRoutes = express.Router();

// Require Business model in our routes module
let Business = require('./business.model');

// Defined store route
businessRoutes.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {
  let business = new Business(req.body);
  business.save()
    .then(business => {
      res.status(200).json({'business': 'business in added successfully'});
    })
    .catch(err => {
    res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
});

// Defined get data(index or listing) route
businessRoutes.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    Business.find(function(err, businesses){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(businesses);
    }
  });
});

// Defined edit route
businessRoutes.route('/edit/:id').get(function (req, res) {
  let id = req.params.id;
  Business.findById(id, function (err, business){
      res.json(business);
  });
});

//  Defined update route
businessRoutes.route('/update/:id').post(function (req, res) {
    Business.findById(req.params.id, function(err, business) {
    if (!business)
      res.status(404).send("data is not found");
    else {
        business.model = req.body.model;
        business.brand = req.body.brand;
        business.price = req.body.price;
        business.photo = req.body.photo;

        business.save().then(business => {
          res.json('Update complete');
      })
      .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("unable to update the database");
      });
    }
  });
});

// Defined delete | remove | destroy route
businessRoutes.route('/delete/:id').get(function (req, res) {
    Business.findByIdAndRemove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, business){
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else res.json('Successfully removed');
    });
});

module.exports = businessRoutes;
```

If i try to define `let Business = Joi.object().keys` it throws me a error.

I'm think i'm supposed to change my `let Business` to something else but i dont know since this is my second nodejs app and i'm kinda new to backend stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do using [joigoose](https://github.com/yoitsro/joigoose)

And now this is my business model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Joigoose = require('joigoose')(mongoose);
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

// Define collection and schema for Business

var joiSchema = Joi.object({
  model: Joi.string().alphanum().min(2).max(255).trim().required(),
  brand: Joi.string().alphanum().min(2).max(255).trim().required(),
  price: Joi.number().positive(),
  photo: Joi.string().max(255).trim()
})

var Business = new Schema(Joigoose.convert(joiSchema))

module.exports = mongoose.model('Business', Business);
```